# Where to place the word "easily"?

Tags: adverbs, word-order, questions, infinitives

Where should I place the word *easily* — before or after *edit and share your bookmarks*?

> Do you want to edit and share your bookmarks easily?

or

> Do you want to easily edit and share your bookmarks?

Context: Promotion text or a kind of slogan for an online service.

Comment: Can you please specify the context of your statement, because it's not making much sense to me right now.

Comment: They are different in some way semantically. The first sentence is talking about the easy of doing something (here, editing and sharing bookmarks). The other talks about editing and sharing bookmarks (incidentally in an easy way). There's a missing preposition in the second sentence, you must edit it.

Comment: Off-topic: Writing advice.  Now if you were asking about how moving 'easily' in the sentence changes the meaning of the sentence, there might be a valid ELU question in there somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Your second sentence <s>is</s> was missing the particle *to*, which is needed. So there are in fact three choices:

> 1. Do you want to edit and share your bookmarks easily?
> 2. Do you want to easily edit and share your bookmarks?
> 3. Do you want easily to edit and share your bookmarks?

(1) and (2) are easily understood, although there are those who don't like split infinitives where *to* is separated from *edit*, so that one might be a second choice.

(3) is the pedant's version and best avoided altogether; if you **say** it, it's fairly easy to make *easily to edit* into a single phrase (so it's not *want easily*). However, it's not obvious when **reading** it.

Put *easily* at the end, where it will apply to both bookmark operations, be understandable and create a fluid sentence. [Edit: Just what's required for an advertising leader question.]

Comment: [Adverb placement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Niching.pdf) is the messiest part of English grammar.

Comment: Do you want to boldly go?

Comment: @mplungjan Well after forty years I still think that would have been better as "Boldly to go where no man has gone before," for a number of reasons, and it has come up here before. (Although that must have been in comments, I can't find it now)

Answer (score 0):

*Easily* is an adverb of manner, and such adverbs are typically found at the end of the clause in which they occur.